# RVIZ image background

Tags: gazebo, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I'm working with RVIZ and I want to put an image (map) in the background instead of the default grid... How can I make this?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253198/rviz-image-background/) by [prvs](https://answers.ros.org/users/28942/prvs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Typically people using the "mesh" visualization marker with the image as the mesh texture. See: http://answers.ros.org/question/40913/draw-image-in-rviz-3d-visualization-frame/

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2017-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0